# I have made a paging system but numbers not displaying

Tags: php, html

I made a paging system. The header is working but I can't see the navigation links I made.

```
$datatable = "items";
$results_per_page = 15;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total FROM ".$datatable;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $total_pages = ceil($row["total"] / $results_per_page); // calculate total pages with results

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
                echo "<a href='questions.php?page=".$i."'";
                if ($i==$page)
                echo " class='curPage'";
                echo ">".$i."</a> ";
    };
```

Why this is not showing

Comment: You are not closing your echo "<a href='questions.php?page=".$i."'"; . This will be closed if the IF statement is succesful if the IF is not succesful it is not closing your a href, you should add an else that closes your href

Comment: Already Closed in Last echo

Comment: Your if is also not working since you are saying if $i==$page do nothing

Comment: echo " class='curPage'>".$i."</a> ";

Comment: Also a quick reminder... `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total FROM ".$datatable;` this code is very vulnerable to _sql injections_... Use binding parameters.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source this is generating, check if any of the tags get included.

Comment: One thing about style as well - as you can see people expect you to use {} round any code involved with an `if` statement - even if it's one line of code.  This is considered good practice.

Comment: @NigelRen while I do actually think it's good practice and avoids potential issues later, it doesn't seem to be so universal. For example, the linux kerner coding style discourages them ("Do not unnecessarily use braces where a single statement will do.")

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
    $link = "<a href='questions.php?page=".$i."'";
    if ($i==$page) {
        $link .= " class='curPage'";
    }
    $link .= ">".$i."</a> ";
    echo $link;
};
```